# ReactNative: Remove underline on TextInput for Android

Tags: android, react-native

I'm struggling on a dumb issue here with styling a TextInput. For some reason, I need to have a border line on a View that contains a TextInput.

Therefore, I don't want the TextInput to display its border line. On iOS, everything's fine without doing anything but on Android, it still displays a black underline.

I've tried to set borderWidth to 0, to set the borderColor to transparent but it doesn't change anything.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found how to fix this. 
There is a special props for Android which is **underlineColorAndroid**. It's set by default so if you want your border line to be invisible, simply do as follow:

```
<TextInput
        ...
        underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}
      />
```

Comment: Even simpler: `underlineColorAndroid="transparent"`

Comment: This should be the default behavior =/